# How can we add placeholder in <apex:input type="Date" />?

Tags: apex, placeholder-text

How can we add placeholder in apex input date field?

html-placeholder and placeholder is not working in date field.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, we can't.

According to the [Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_input.htm), apex:input actually renders as html input:

> ```
> <apex:input value="{!inputValue}" id="theTextInput"/>
> ```
>
> The example above renders the following HTML:
>
> ```
> <input id="theTextInput" type="text" name="theTextInput" />
> ```

I tried looking in the HTML Living Standard [documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#date-state-(type=date)) to see if there is a solution for this and found the following in regards to **input of type date**:

> The following content attributes must not be specified and do not
>   apply to the element: accept, alt, checked, dirname, formaction,
>   formenctype, formmethod, formnovalidate, formtarget, height,
>   maxlength, minlength, multiple, pattern, **placeholder**, size, src, and
>   width.

That's why html-placeholder attribute did not work in this case.

As a workaround I would use labels instead of placeholders.